# average score in react jsx

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I am trying to display the average score from a list pulled from a firebase database and I honestly can't work that out. the full code down below will only display a list of scores. I believe i need to loop trough the Object.keys(learnerObjects) list and get the single scores from learnerObjects[id].score but i  am not sure how to get the single average data and display it on screen. please help?

PART WHERE I WANT TO PLACE THE AVERAGE SCORE

```
<h1 className="display-4 text-center">List Learners</h1>
              
              {Object.keys(learnerObjects).map((id) =>{
               
                 
                return(
                    <h3>{learnerObjects[id].score}</h3>
                )
              })}
```

ALL CODE FILE

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import {db, auth} from "../firebase";

const HomePage = () => {
    
  const history = useHistory()
  var [learnerObjects, setLearnerObjects] = useState({});
  var [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");

  const handleLogout = () => {
    auth.signOut();
    history.push('/')
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    db.child("learners").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val() != null)
        setLearnerObjects({
          ...snapshot.val(),
        });
      else setLearnerObjects({});
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="display-4 text-center">List Learners</h1>
          
          {Object.keys(learnerObjects).map((id) =>{
           
             
            return(
                <h3>{learnerObjects[id].score}</h3>
            )
          })}
           
          <button style={{backgroundColor: '#77acf1', width: '18%'}}onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-7">
          <table className="table table-borderless table-stripped">
            <thead className="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>View/Edit</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Object.keys(learnerObjects).map((id) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={id}>
                    <td>{learnerObjects[id].firstName}</td>
                    <td>{learnerObjects[id].lastName}</td>

                    <td>
                      <Link to="/Contacts">
                        <button
                          className="btn text-primary"
                          onClick={() => {
                            setCurrentId(id);
                          }}
                        >
                          <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                      </Link>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an inline sum using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0) // === 6
```

In your case, it would look something like this, as a complete expression:

```
Object.values(learnerObjects).reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0)/(learnerObjects.length || 1)
```